# In create view search by "ID"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I redirect from my create view to my edit view after entering an ID in my input field? I tried with the following code but I'm not getting an ID in URL.

**Controller**

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

public function edit(visitor $visitor)
{
    $visitors = visitor::all();

    $find = Input::get('find');
    visitor::where('id', 'LIKE', '%'.$find.'%')->get();

    return view('create', compact('visitors'));
}
```

**View**

```php
<form method="post" action="{{ route('visitors.store') }}" class="form-group">
    @csrf
    @foreach($visitors as $visitor)
        <label for="visitor">Visitor No:</label>
        <a href="{{ URL::to('visitors/' . $visitor->id . '/edit') }}"></a>
    @endforeach
    <input type="text" name="find" class="form-control" value="{{ $newvisitnum }}">
</form>
```

`$newvisitnum` is my auto-increment ID.

```
<pre>
    Getting error of "Undefined variable: visitors
</pre>
```

In the URL it should appear like this "visitors/{id}/edit" and should fetch all records to edit view associated with that ID.

Comment: Your error is undefined variable visitors, right? Where have you defined $visitors?

Comment: @editor, I don't want to add "Edit" near "Visitor No", just want a search functionality in "Visitor No" field by ID which will redirect to Edit view with visitors/{id}/edit

Comment: @jameson2012, under foreach loop

Comment: If you define it after the foreach loop, how do you expect the loop to loop throught it - it won't exist yet. Hence your error

Comment: @jameson2012 then how can I get? if user inputs a value (ID) in "Visitor No" it should get in to edit view with its details... please explain

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure your routes/web.php file has "visitors/{vistor}/edit" as one of the routes.

Comment: Yes, I have a resource route: Route::resource('visitors', 'VisitorsController');